# Gathering data in 2D array and using setValues()

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to run through 600 files and get two pieces of information from each file. I need then to paste that information in a sheet so I can use it elsewhere. I have code working that is too slow, so that is why I am trying to shift it to an array. Here is the code I have:

```
      var fileCount;
      var dataArray = [];
      var files = folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    for(fileCount = 0; fileCount < 650; fileCount++) {

      currentFile = files.next();
      Logger.log(currentFile.getName());

      var fileID = currentFile.getId();
      var rowKey = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID).getSheetByName("Summary").getRange("A1").getValue();

//the error appears at the next line
      dataArray[fileCount][0] = fileID;
      dataArray[fileCount][1] = rowKey;          

      targetSheet.getRange(1,1,fileCount,2).setValues(dataArray);

      spreadsheet.toast("File " + fileCount + " data pasted.", "", -1);
      Logger.log(rowKey + ' : ' + fileCount + ' : ' + fileCount);
    }
  }
```

And the error I'm getting:

> Sorry, Error Occured: TypeError: Cannot set property "0.0" of
>   undefined to "11GI2qs6LP1uQIYKIVtqX-rQ9JRC_-lH1NwVh0GLVn8Q".

Am I not initialising/declaring the array properly?
Am I needing to rely on some library or something?

Answer (score 1):

I got it - if anyone else is interested:

```
      var fileCount;
      var foldercount = 0;
      var dataArray = [];
      var files = folder.getFiles();

      for(fileCount = 0; files.hasNext(); fileCount++) {

          currentFile = files.next();
          Logger.log(currentFile.getName());

          var fileID = currentFile.getId();
          var rowKey = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID).getSheetByName("Summary").getRange("A1").getValue();

          dataArray.push([fileID, rowKey]);
          //dataArray[fileCount][0] = fileID;
          //dataArray[fileCount][1] = rowKey;          

          spreadsheet.toast("File " + fileCount + " data pasted.", "", -1);
          Logger.log(rowKey + ' : ' + fileCount + ' : ' + fileCount);
        }

      targetSheet.getRange(1,1,fileCount,2).setValues(dataArray);
```